Raster interpolation only works on one side of the raster
I'm trying to interpolate couple of pixels on a raster. But it's not working out for me, and I'm a little startled on this issue. I'm trying to use the Fill NoData tool of gdal, and it's only partly working as you can see in the second screenshot.

Only the right side of the raster interpolates well, but almost nothing is working for the real problematic parts, which are top-bottom and left sides.

I have tried with couple of combinations for max distance and smoothing iterations fields, but result is same. Can anyone point me to what I'm missing here?
Also the actual raster I got was in angular projection, and I reprojected it to a metric projection using the reproject tool and tried with that input as well without any luck.
